# Using POST data in a query with Ajax and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a website that uses bootstrap tabs so I'm trying to make everything work with minimal refreshing with Ajax, however I'm having trouble with getting an ajax post to work with a mysql query until the page is refreshed.

Once a button is pressed the value is grabbed from the ID of that element by Ajax and a bootstrap tab is opened. This is where I want the data to be passed so the results are relevant to the option that the user has selected.

**Modules.php**

```
<a href="#parts" id="100" class="completed"></a>
```

(Ajax request)

```
$(".completed").click(function() {

var element = $(this);
var ID = $(this).attr("id");
var dataString = 'id='+ ID;

$.ajax({
      cache: false,
      url: "includes/scripts/ajax/module_parts.php",
      type: "POST",
      datatype: "text",
      data: dataString,
      success: function (html) {
        $('#moduleNum').html(ID);
        console.log(ID);
      },
      error: function(data, errorThrown)
      {
          alert('request failed :'+errorThrown);
      }
 });

return false;

});
```

**module_parts.php**

```
$module_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id']); 

echo $module_id;

$query = mysqli_query ($connection, "SELECT number FROM Modules WHERE number = '".$module_id."'");
```

I know that the post is working correctly because I tried turning the post into a session then when refreshing the page the data was displayed.

Also the data is displaying correctly when appending the ID to an html element.

Many thanks,
Zack.

Comment: So if the post is working, it's the query that fails. Have you looked at the error report with `mysqli_error()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes the query is working correctly if I enter a static value. It's just the post data from ajax is blank until a refresh even when I just print out the variable.

Comment: `$('#moduleNum').html(ID);` ?? I would expect it to be `$('#moduleNum').html(html);` normally.

Comment: Thank you. I Just figured that out now. I'm new to ajax so I did not realise that everything has to be added into an html element, I thought you could just echo out what was need on the page once it's been created aha! Thank you everyone that's helped me with suggestions and improvements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as a side note, I prefer to do this with ajax shenanigans. It may help you ...

Altered the anchor element:

```
<a href="#parts" id="100" class="completed" rel="completed">Click me</a>
```

Javascript:

```
ID = $(this).attr("id")

$('body').on('click', '[rel="completed"]', function() {
    $.post('includes/scripts/ajax/module_parts.php', { id : ID }, function(data) {
        $('#moduleNum').html(data); // data or ID ?
    }).fail(function() {
        alert('request failed');
    });
});
```

The `$('body').on` part helps to keep scripts alive should you insert new links or buttons. It means anything within the body tag but you can and maybe should narrow it down further such as the surrounding div.

I, personally, find this way to be easier to deal with, especially if there is just simple data passing to and fro.

Answer (score 0):

1) Check if id is passed by post and get by module_parts.

2) I'd rather use object when passing post data via ajax:

```
data: { id : ID }
```

3) Good option to check ajax requests is to use Firebug (on Console), you can check requests details without echoing.

Answer (score 0):

At least two things in your script need resolution.

datatype should be changed to dataType (text is not one of jQuery's "intelligent guess" types (xml, json, script, or html), so dataType must be correctly spelled.

You should prevent the default behavior of the anchor click event.

```
(".completed").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault
    ...
```

There may be some additional problems, but these two jumped out at me.